# Printing an array in a directory, and opening files

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the code below, however I don't understand why it is printing out a blank message box? Additionally, there is only one for each day, and it is saying there is 2 files?

How do I print these back effectively, second, how do I then use that to open the sheet?

The files are written as `samadmin15112018_??????.csv` Where the question marks are a time stamp which I don't know.

```
Sub runFA()
Const yourfilepath = "R:\samsdrive\sam\test\"      
Dim s As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim v() As String

    s = Dir(yourfilepath & "samadmin" & format(Sheets("Name").Range("C3"), "yyyymmdd") & "_*.csv")

    v = Split(vbNullString)

Do Until s = ""

    x = x + 1
    ReDim Preserve v(x + 1)
    s = Dir()

Loop
If UBound(v) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are " & UBound(v) & " workbooks", vbOKOnly
    MsgBox v(x + 1)
Else
   If v(0) <> "" Then Workbooks.Open (yourfilepath & v(0))
   MsgBox ("There are 0 ")
End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282399/search-list-and-open-excel-sheets-with-only-the-start-of-the-name#comment93447291_53282713) on the answer this code is adapted from. Your array indexing is off by one due to the error in that answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it wont compile then @Comintern

Comment: You need `Dim v() As String` instead of `ReDim v(1)`. `v = Split(vbNullString)` has to come before the loop.

Comment: Ah so you're right sir! Does `v = Split(vbNullString)` just initialize v as an empty string? Sorry if its basic but I am just trying to understand! Secondly - still saying theirs 2 wrokbooks?

Comment: That's a bit of a trick. `Split(vbNullString)` returns an array with an upper bound of -1.  That means when you resize it to add the first element, you can simply use `ReDim Preserve yourArray(UBound(yourArray) + 1)` because that gives you `0` as the calculated upper bound.

Comment: I have just been doing some research around it, that seems like a very clever tactic. However this `UBound(v)` is still outputting? Additionally the array still wont print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53282713/4088852)...

You were getting an empty element because the original code resized the array for the first element, which meant that `v(0)` was ***always*** going to be `vbNullString`.  With string arrays, you can take advantage of the `Split` function's behavior of returning an array with a `UBound` of -1 and an `LBound` of 0 if you're going to add elements to it dynamically:

```
Sub runFA()
    Const targetPath = "R:\samsdrive\sam\test\"
    Dim located() As String
    located = Split(vbNullString)

    Dim result As String
    result = Dir$(targetPath & "samadmin" & Format$(Sheets("Name").Range("C3"), "yyyymmdd") & "_*.csv")

    Do Until result = vbNullString
        ReDim Preserve located(UBound(located) + 1)
        located(UBound(located)) = result
        result = Dir$()
    Loop

    If UBound(located) <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are " & (UBound(located) + 1) & " workbooks", vbOKOnly
    Else
        Workbooks.Open targetPath & result
    End If
End Sub
```

A couple other things to note

- I changed the variable names from single letter identifiers to something a little easier to read and understand.
- The indentation is now consistant.
- It uses the string typed functions for `Dir` and `Format`.
- You don't need to track the count of results with `x` at all.
- If you only have one element in the results array, you can simply use `result` - there isn't any reason to index back into the array.

Comment: Thank you @Comintern. That's an extremely useful post, not just for the answer but understanding a better way to program, especially only referring to result! My only problem (and I don't think its to do with the code) is that it simply doesn't count anything, even when specifying the full file path and full name completely known, Always returns 0. However if I output `targetPath & "samadmin" & Format$(Sheets("Name").Range("C3"), "yyyymmdd") & "_*.csv"` then paste into windows explorer, it opens the files for me! Most confusing! Any ideas?